# How to write values() method of sortedMap in Java?

Tags: java, interface, sortedmap

I'm curious whether anyone has tips on how to begin writing the `values()` method of a class implementing Java's `sortedmap` interface. If possible, example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is your sorted map implemented?  This is really just a special case of implementing `entrySet()` (as is `keySet()`) so think about that first.

Comment: This highly depends on your sorted map implementation.  Have you already worked out a means to traverse your map entries in order?  If so, then the implementation of values() would be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap, which is an implementation of the SortedMap interface, might be a good place to do some research:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TreeMap.java.html

Answer (score 0):

*Unless your `SortedMap` implementation keeps a list (or any other traversable collection) of the map's values*, your `values()` implementation is very likely to be exactly this (which is quite universal):

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    List<V> values = new ArrayList<V>();
    for (K key: keySet()) {
        values.add(get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very inefficient. Here's a tip: check out `Map.entrySet()`

Comment: `entrySet()` will still end up iterating over the `keySet()`, looking each one up and instantiating `Map.Entry` instances. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing that iterating over the entry set avoids the n lookups your code does (via the call to `get()`, which is expensive), since you can just use `entry.getValue()` directly. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Focus on implementing `entrySet()`. Once you have that, do this:

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    List<V> values = new ArrayList<V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entrySet()) {
        values.add(entry.getValue());
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: You will certainly have to explain why focusing on `entrySet()` is more beneficial. Besides, the OP asked specifically about `values()`; it is possible that `entrySet()` is already written, and who knows, maybe he can't even modify the existing `entrySet()` implementation.

Comment: With regards to your comment on my answer: you are concluding that this approach is more efficient because a hypothetical, possibly-not-within-the-OP's-control implementation of `entrySet()` is more efficient than issuing a series of `get()` operations. Frankly, without more information from the OP about what they *really* are trying to accomplish (and what they already have written), it's impossible to conclude one more efficient approach than another.